# How to set amount values in JTextField. with 2 decimal places? Pls suggest

Tags: swing, jtextfield

Amount values in JTextField. with 2 decimal places?
JMaskFormatter and other not metting my requirement

Comment: [Implementing a Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the similar code snippet which you could try

**NEW UPDATE (Working successfully):**

```
JTextField yourTextFieldName = new JTextField();
DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String formattedText = dc.format(Double.parseDouble(yourTextFieldName.getText()));
System.out.println(formattedText);
```

OLD VERSION(Not reccomented):

```
JTextField yourTextFieldName = new JTextField();
yourTextFieldName.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(custom.getValue())));
```

Comment: For pure formatting, a `JFormattedTextField` would be preferred

Comment: I have added a new code snippet which I tried and it's working successfully.

Comment: Now type into the field - it won't hold the format, not will it restrict what you can type, which is more alone the lines of what I "think" the OP is trying to ask ... but who knows, the questions is so open to interpretation it's impossible to answer